# How to use File.separator in Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

Every time I use `File.separator` in Java code, I get the error because `'\'` is an escape character in Windows and Java doesn't recognise "quotes".

I tried doing this: `String[] split = strData.toString().split(File.pathSeparator);`, but it crashes with following error message:

```
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
^

File.pathSeparator = ;
File.separator = \
strData.toString() = C:\Users\server\Desktop\minecraft\plugins\krneki
```

Comment: can you please show us what `strData.toString()` return?

Comment: also `File.pathSeparator`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the argument of `String.split` is a regular expression, you need to quote the separator for it to be treated as a literal:

```
String[] split = strData.toString().split(Pattern.quote(File.pathSeparator));
```